# Android layout: One image & Two EditText views per row

Tags: android, image, layout, android-edittext, row

I am having difficulty in setting a layout for my activity. I am trying to achieve a list layout, with each row on the list containing and Icon, and 2 EditText views beside each icon.

For example, a GMail icon, and user can enter their email and password into the view.

I've tried a couple of approaches and cannot seem to get one working. The closest I've come is one EditText view per row but this is not what I am trying to achieve.

Here's a look at my xml. If anyone has any suggestions on how I can improve that would be great.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >
    <RelativeLayout >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"

            android:layout_width="150px"
            android:layout_height="150px"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            android:src="@drawable/gm" >
        </ImageView>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/secondLine"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignRight="@id/logo"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            >
        </EditText>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstLine"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/logo"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/secondLine">
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you seen the article [Layout Tricks: Creating Efficient Layouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html). It has an example that sounds exactly like what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to read up more on layouts. You are setting your image to top AND bottom of your parent. Which makes perfectly no sense. If this is your listview item row, change to this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" >

<RelativeLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="150px"
    android:layout_height="150px"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/gm" >
</ImageView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/logo"
    >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/logo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/firstLine"
    >
</EditText>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked well, for sure I need to read up on layouts I've forgotten a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use [listview](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) and write custom adapter which contain your custom row.